# Jhipster - add translation for new alerts

Tags: angular, internationalization, jhipster, alert

In order to add a new alert when a user clicks a button, I followed the instructions from the [jhipster official website](https://www.jhipster.tech/using-angular/) on the section about the *Notification System* .

The function that executes when the user clicks the button looks like this now :

```
 randomMethod():void {
     this.alertService.get().push(
      this.alertService.addAlert(
          {
              type: 'danger',
              msg: 'you should not have pressed this button!',
              timeout: 3000,
              toast: false,
              scoped: true
          },
          this.alertService.get()
      )

  );
```

The new alert does display but, because I have **internationalization** enabled, my alert-message is displayed like this:

```
translation-not-found[you should not have pressed this button!]
```

What do I need to do to configure the translation for my alert ?

EDIT : it think I need to modify one or more files in my *src\main\webapp\i18n* folder

Comment: Yes you must put a key rather than a message and then you must edit the file in src\main\webapp\i18n matching your language and page and your key.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou Should they key be similar to the one passed to `jhiTranslate` property? I understand how that works.

Comment: Yes that's the same key, it can be a path using dot notation.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou It works great. Thank you for the help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like [@GaëlMarziou](https://stackoverflow.com/users/93960/ga%C3%ABl-marziou) answered in the comments of the question :

If you have internationalization enabled in your project, in the `msg` property you will NOT introduce the message itself. Instead, you will have to provide a key that points towards a file in `src\main\webapp\i18n` matching the language, key and page.

For example, if you want to put an alert in the **home page** and you have chosen, among others, **English** as a language, you will have to do something like this :

```
  randomMethod():void {
     this.alertService.get().push(
      this.alertService.addAlert(
          {
              type: 'danger',
              msg: 'yourAppName.home.buttonAllertMessage',
              timeout: 3000,
              toast: false,
              scoped: true
          },
          this.alertService.get()
      )
  );
```

And you will have to add the new property (`buttonAllertMessage`) in the `src\main\webapp\i18n\en\home.json` file like so :

```
{
  "home": {
    "title": "Welcome",
    "subtitle": "This is your homepage",
    "logged": {
      "message": "You are logged in as user \"{{username}}\"."
    },
    "question": "If you have any question on JHipster:",
    "link": {
      "homepage": "JHipster homepage",
      "stackoverflow": "JHipster on Stack Overflow",
      "bugtracker": "JHipster bug tracker",
      "chat": "JHipster public chat room",
      "follow": "follow @jhipster on Twitter"
    },
    "like": "If you like JHipster, don't forget to give us a star on",
    "github": "GitHub",
    "buttonAllertMessage" : "you should not have pressed this button!"
  }
}
```

And then you should do the same for the other languages you have configured.